# New Fuzzy Lookup

Tags: ssis

I am new to the SSIS Fuzzy Group facility. Say I had one million records that I would like to cleanse on a daily basis. Some of those records may change e.g. surname or date of birth incorrect. Also new records are created every day. I have two questions:

1. Is the output table (the table that contains: key_out and key_in) truncated each time the SSIS package is run or does it remain in tact from last time it was run?
2. If it remains intact, then is there a way of only matching new records to save time? If you only input new records then do all the previously matched records remain in the output table matched together or do you lose them?

Comment: You can use a `Lookup Transformation` for answer to question 2:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx

Comment: @Jeff Orris, thanks.  What is a typical value for 'maximum number of matches'? I thought this value would be unlimited? Can you post an answer as your comment answered my question.

Comment: updated answer to your comment is in the answer I left...by the way there is a `Fuzzy Lookup Transformation` as well

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question #2:

You can use a `Lookup Transformation`

•"If there is no matching entry in the reference dataset, no join occurs. By default, the Lookup transformation treats rows without matching entries as errors. However, you can configure the Lookup transformation to redirect such rows to a no match output. For more information, see Lookup Transformation Editor (General Page) and Lookup Transformation Editor (Error Output Page)."

•"If there are multiple matches in the reference table, the Lookup transformation returns only the first match returned by the lookup query. If multiple matches are found, the Lookup transformation generates an error or warning only when the transformation has been configured to load all the reference dataset into the cache. In this case, the Lookup transformation generates a warning when the transformation detects multiple matches as the transformation fills the cache."

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thanks. What value do you have for: "maximum number of matches". I would expect this to be unlimited.

Comment: @w0051977 I've been searching for you but can't define a definitive answer.  I would assume unlimited because doesn't state in MSDN...just states once a match occurs and cache is filled then generates and exception.